# Immature or wise beyond your years quote from the Ender's Game books

Tags: novel, enders-game, quotes, orson-scott-card

I've been searching for tens of minutes for this quote from the *Ender's Game* series of books by Orson Scott Card, but can't find it.

The son of the family Ender befriends is mentioned by the elders to be mature. There is a vignette which describes the way the son has a knack with few words to make the elders ashamed with wisdom beyond his years.

Can anyone tell me the quote?

Comment: "the family Ender befriends" makes me think you can narrow it down to _Speaker for the Dead_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're talking about Libo, Novinha's oldest son, in *[Speaker for the Dead](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1158)*.

There is an incident when Pipo and Dona Crist were having a discussion, and Dona Crist asked Libo to leave so they could talk in private:

> He was gone before she finished her sentence, with a quick nod of his
> head, a half-smile that said, Yes, I understand, and a deftness of
> movement that made his exit more eloquent proof of his discretion than
> if he had argued to stay. By this Pipo knew that Libo was annoyed at
> being asked to leave; **he had a knack for making adults feel vaguely
> immature by comparison to him**.

Is this the incident you had in mind?

Comment: Yes thanks. Solution accepted. Let me know if this comment is redundant.